# Did I say "I shall bring glory to God in all that I do." right?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, adverbs

I have to write a list of goals for this year for my Japanese class and one of them is "I shall bring glory to God in all things" or something of similar meaning.

Using my many Japanese grammar, conjugation, etc. workbooks and resources that my teacher has equipped us with in past years, I came up with 「私はすべてのことに神の栄光のためにすべきである。」

For those of you who are fluent in Japanese, is this the best way to translate my thoughts?

Comment: のためにすべきである。」   is [You shall] as in a legal context or maybe as in a religious directive (commandments)  __________________ The following would be better:  ---  shall 【助動】 〔決意などを表して〕～するつもりである ____________ or in a more usual language :   するつもりです or するよう努力します

Comment: @H.Ha Thank you so much!  So I could say 「私はすべてのことに神の栄光をするよう努力します。」and it would make sense?

Comment: I'd translate it into すべては神の栄光のために.

Comment: I'm 6 years late to the party, but I'd say すべてのこと[において]{LLLL}.

Answer (score 1):

直訳調
 「私はすべてのことを神に栄光をもたらすよう努力します。」

意図を優先した訳
 「私はすべてのことを神の栄光にかなうよう努力します。」

（映画の字幕のように）英語のボキャブラリーを無視した訳
 「私はすべての行為を、神の栄光を飾るべく努力します。」／ 「私はすべて、神の栄光の御名を汚さぬよう努力します。」

最後の訳例は「名を惜しむ」文化、「恥の概念」を強く押し出してみました。
『菊と刀』は古くさいですが、アニメの「金田一少年の事件簿」では「じっちゃんの名にかけて！」と今でも言っています。